# PostgreSQL: Convert timestamp to time - or retrieve only time from timestamp column

Tags: postgresql

What I want is something equivalent to this:

```
select to_time( to_timestamp ( '03.04.2014 12:34:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS' ) )
```

Problem here is that to_time does not exist. I want this to result in

```
12:34:00 (without the date)
```

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
select timestamp '2014-04-03 12:34:00'::time
```

I prefer ANSI date/timestamp literals as they are shorter to write than `to_timestamp()`

The above is equivalent to:

```
select to_timestamp ('03.04.2014 12:34:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')::time
```

the `::time` is Postgres' short hand notation for casting a value.

The following would be complete ANSI SQL if you want that:

```
select cast(timestamp '2014-04-03 12:34:00' as time)
```

Comment: It is not necessary to cast to timestamp first. Cast to time directly: `select '2014-04-03 12:34:00'::time` and `select cast('2014-04-03 12:34:00' as time)`

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: I don't "cast" to a timestamp. I use an ANSI timestamp *literal*.

Comment: Isn't this a cast:? `select timestamp '2014-04-03 12:34:00'`. And this `select time '2014-04-03 12:34:00'`

Comment: The first will yield a timestamp data type and the second a time data type. `select pg_typeof(time '2014-04-03 12:34:00');`

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: `timestamp '2014-04-03 12:34:00'` is an ANSI timestamp literal, not a cast. I'm surprised that `time '2014-04-03 12:34:00'` works because that should be an illegal time literal

Comment: Thanks - Just what I needed :D - (EDIT) Almost. :) I have a timestamp column that I want to cast to time, but select cast(a as time) does not seem to work for me.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `time '2014-04-03 12:34:00'` works because *PostgreSQL is more flexible in handling date/time input than the SQL standard requires* http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-datetime.html

Comment: This is valid: `select timestamp 'January 8 04:05:06 1999 PST'` Is it ANSI?

Comment: Got it working - Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems there is a difference in what kind of time it is casted to depending on wether you use it in a select clause or a where clause. In the select clause it is time with timezone and in the where clause it is time without timezone.

Comment: [From the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS): _It is also possible to specify a type cast using a function-like syntax_ `select integer '1'`

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto *Also, the names interval, time, and timestamp can only be used in this fashion if they are double-quoted, because of syntactic conflicts.* So: `time '12:34:00'` is a time literal, while `"time"('12:34:00')` is a cast (-like function call).

Comment: what if there is milliseconds? this won't remove it